# while building android studio show error..?

Tags: android, android-studio-3.1.3

i am using **android studio 3.1.3**

while building ill get those errors

```
Emulator: emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!

Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Download and install Intel emulator Accelerator(HAXM installer)

Answer (score 1):

If you have Intel processor try to install HAXM either from SDK manager or from [intel website](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-intel-haxm). You should also check if Hardware Virtualization is enabled in BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly while creating the emulator you have to tick mark the hardware selection option.
You could delete the chosen AVD and create a new one.

Read more in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel) and [here](https://dzone.com/articles/hardware-acceleration-android).

Also as rightly suggested, to make an emulator your Virtualization should be enabled in the BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

The Android emulator needs sometimes hardware acelleration features, so that's why it prompts the error.

You have here all the documentation about the Hardware Acelleration and a full explanation how to install it:

[Documentation Configure Emulator graphics rendering and hardware acceleration](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration)

If you dont wan't to read the full doc, here's what you need to do:

1. Open Android SDK Manager and install **"*Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator*"**
2. Find the folder path where you just download it (You can find it on the top)
3. Once open the path open the subfolder `extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager` and install `intelhaxm-android.exe`*
4. Restart Android Studio and try to run the emulator.

*If it prompts an error about virtualization technology you should enable it on your BIOS, there's a lot of tutorials on internet depending on your O.S

Hope it helps you